# it is not inserting a value in the database

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to insert a value in the database but when I open up the database the value is not inserted in the table. Now all of the code is correct in terms of no misspelling or anything like that but why isn't it inserting a value in the DB table?

I just have to say that this field is not a primary key field, I am just testing this field which is a non primary key field, will it not insert a value in the db table if the primary key value is not inserted?

Below is the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $username="xxx";
    $password="xxx";
    $database="mobile_app";

    mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


    $sql="INSERT INTO Session (Course)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[course]')";

    mysql_close();

    if (isset($_POST['course'])) {

    $_SESSION['course'] = $_POST['course'];

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: You never execute your query, you just define a variable that holds it.

Comment: @DanielA.White vulnerable? it's not even executing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the Primary Key in there. You can't add a row to the database without specifying the Primary Key, unless the Primary Key is auto-generated (an Identity).

Edit: as Damien pointed out, you'll need to add the following line after you define the $sql variable.

```
mysql_query($sql)
```

Comment: Yeah, and use mysql_query() maybe?

Comment: Damien is right, I completely forgot to use mysql query. I am such an idiot. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah didn't see that, nice spot Damien I've added it to my edit, +1 for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well mattytommo about need to insert a primary key value as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is NO . You cannot insert a value into the database like this (w/o inserting some value for the primary key)

Comment: He can, PK isn't necessary afaik (and it might just be an AI). Just that he's not doing it.

Comment: But if the Db has a PK , then its value needs to be inserted unless otherwise auto-generated

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you execute the SQL query somewhere? At the moment, all you do is to assign the sql query to a variable. It is never executed.

(Also, do a google search for Bobby Tables...)

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the "mysql_query" statement ?

```
  mysql_query($sql);
```

**You must change the way you wrote the query. It is OPEN for Attacks !**

Comment: Well, _this_ is vulnerable to injections

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Yea. I mentioned it in my answer and upvoted for the first comment of this question by Daniel

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to _correct_ the answer, instead of saying "this is the code, but don't do like this" :)

Comment: @DamienPirsy : Totally agree. I removed the query stuff from my answer

Comment: @DamienPirsy: .by the way i did'nt do php for 5 years i guess.so not sure abt the methods to sanitize

Answer (score 1):

Change your given segment of code to this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $username="xxx";
  $password="xxx";
  $database="mobile_app";
  mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
  @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
  if (isset($_POST['course'])) {
    $_SESSION['course'] = $_POST['course'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO Session (Course) VALUES (' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['course'] ) . "' );";
  }
  mysql_query( $sql );
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well .. you have to execute the query, to actually that `INSERT` statement to take effect.

As for the code in general, you must have learned from so ancient tutorial. The `mysql_*` function now are more then 10 years old, and no longer maintained. **You should not write any new code with `mysql_*` functions.** PHP community is already moving to [make them deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). You should be using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.

And **stop abusing the error suppression operator `@`**. It is slow and considered to be harmful in most cases.

Instead yo should write something like:

```
// connect to database
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mobile_app;charset=UTF-8', 
                      'username', 'password');
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

// set up the query 
$query = 'INSERT INTO Session (Course) VALUES(:course)';
$statement = $connection->prepare( $query );
$statement->bindParam( ':course', $_POST['course'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 63 );
// last parameter is max length of field in the table

// perform the query
if ( $statement->execute() )
{
     // everything worked
}
```

If you want to learn how to use PDO with MySQL: [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) will help. If think that MySQLi API would be a better choice, then you will have to find some on your own.